# For any sequence of r .v .'s $\{X_n\},$ if $E(X_n^2) \rightarrow 0 $, then $\frac{S_n-E(S_n)}{n}\rightarrow 0$ is true in pr?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

For any sequence of r .v .'s $\{X_n\},$ if $E(X_n^2) \rightarrow 0 $, then $\frac{S_n-E(S_n)}{n}\rightarrow 0$ is true in pr . but not necessarily a .e.? Here is my attempt.

We are given $E(X_n^2) \rightarrow 0 $ this implies $X_n\rightarrow 0$ in probabilty. Consider $\frac{S_n}{n}$.Let $\frac{S_{n_k}}{n_k}$ be a susequence. Since $X_n\rightarrow 0$ in probability, then $X_{n_k}\rightarrow 0$ in probabilty. By Riesz theorem there exists $X_{n_{k_j}}$ converges a.e to $0$. Consider the subsequence $\frac{S_{n_{k_j}}}{n_{k_j}}$. One can conclude the cesaro sum $\frac{S_{n_{k_j}}}{n_{k_j}}\rightarrow 0$ a.e.. Since for every subsequence have found a further subsequence thhat converges a.e. then $\frac{S_n}{n}\rightarrow 0$ in probability. Does my answer make sense? If no can someone please provide me with the proper solution?

Comment: Are you asking about $\frac{S_n - \mathbb E[S_n]}n$ or $\frac{S_n}n$?

Comment: Since $E(x_n^2)\rightarrow 0$ then I am assuming WLOG $E[X_n]=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arguement is not valid. If you repalce $(X_n)$ by  a subsequence the corresponding partial sums will not be a subsequence of $(S_n)$.

$P(|\frac {S_n-ES_n} {n} >\epsilon)\leq \frac 1 {n^{2} \epsilon^{2}} E(S_n)^{2}$ since $E(S_n-ES_n)^{2} \leq ES_n^{2}$. Now use Cauchy Schwartz inequality to see that $ES_n^{2} \leq n \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} EX_k^{2}$. Finally use the fact that $EX_n^{2} \to 0$ implies $\frac 1 n \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} EX_k^{2} \to 0$.

Comment: I see. I forgot about the fact that the partial sums will include values that are not part of my subsequence $X_{n_{k_j}}$. Thank you.